Screen brightness not regulated by /sys/class/backlight/ on Lenovo laptop. How to explore a potentially deeper issue?
Brightness slider works, either directly from configuration, or via Fn+F5/F6. However, the slider changing does not change the actual screen brightness, which remains at maximum.
In /sys/class/backlight/ there is only one entry, either ideapad or acpi_video0, depending on wether I have GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor" or GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video" in /etc/default/grub. The screen brightness slider does change the values of brightness and actual_brightness in these directories as intended, but said changes do not translate on an physical brightness change. It seems as if the software is working as intended, but it is not translating into a hardware reaction. I have tried changing several options in the /etc/default/grub file, including GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.backlight=0", but nothing seems to work. I am quite convinced at this point that the issue does not lie within /etc/default/grub.
I have Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. My laptop has NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX, with RYZEN 7000 SERIES. I tried to see if there is an issue with the driver, but upon command nvidia-smi I only get NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running. I did install nvidia-utils-550, so I do not know where this is coming from.
I am not sure how to further debug this without messing with things I do not know about, but the screen brightness is hurting my eyes and draining my laptop battery quickly. Please kindly share any suggestion on how to act from here, how to debug this further, or a fix if you have found a similar issue. Thank you very much.
